# Jena for java 1.7

Tags: jena, apache-jena

Is there any version compatible with java 1.7v in Jena

I'm getting following error and i think it is because of incompatibility

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jena/query/QueryFactory : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at onetime.main(onetime.java:37)
```

any suggestion would be extremely helpful

Comment: your `onetime.main` was compiled with Java 8 ?

Comment: no my version is 1.7

Comment: I believe the 2.x is supporting Java 1.7, you should be able to use Jena 2.13

Comment: ok let me try that...btw thanks