# Service now apis and jena

Tags: jena, servicenow, apache-jena

Can anyone suggest me how i can use **ServiceNow** Api's and i did a bit of research on it and found it requires authentication. Is it true?

also

I need jena for java 1.7 inorder to use sparql query.It is showing 
major.minor version 52.0 which is because jena is expecting java 1.8 but i
want to work on 1.7

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jena/query/ResultSet : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I know this isn't a technical question but any kind of help would be very helpful.

Comment: Use Apache Jena 2.13.0.  Or upgrade to java8 (it runs Java 7 code and is more fun to write).

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856912/jena-for-java-1-7

Comment: Ok let me try this 2.13, i need to work on java 1.7 only

Answer (score 1):

yes typically most ServiceNow APIs require authentication. You can use either Basic or OAuth2. You can find more info about it here: http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=REST_API#Security. Hope this helps.